# OSX Yosemite Terminal won't run java MyClass.class, Error: Could not find or load main class MyClass.class

Tags: java, terminal, program-entry-point, methodnotfound

I'm running `OSX Yosemite` with `jdk1.8.0_31`. While I was testing `printf` functionality, I realized that I can't run any `.class` files in `terminal` with command: `java MyClass`. Here's the error I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MyClass.class
```

Also I can run classes with `main` method perfectly fine in Eclipse, and I can compile `MyClass.java` with java compiler in terminal by `$javac MyClass.java`.

I googled it and asked around, still couldn't find anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `MainExp` in a package?  This problem usually occurs because you are not running the class from within the correct context.  You should make sure that you are at the root directory of the package of the class, then use the fully qualified name of the class to execute it `java some.package.MainExp` for example...

Comment: @SebastianO. How many classes do you have? Are `MainExp` and `MyClass` two separate classes?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Yes it is. It's in package `com.foo.root`. I ran both `java MainPackage.bin.com.foo.root.MainExp` and `java MainExp` in all directories starting from `root` to all the way to outside `MainPackage` project folder. Same error.

Comment: @iRuth: There's just one class, `MainExp`.

Comment: @All: For clarity, I changed the description to have one class (`MyClass`).

Comment: What does your class path setup look like?

Comment: @Mark: My `$CLASSPATH` is not set. Within the directory that has `MyClass.java`, I can run `javac MyClass.java` and it runs & creates the `MyClass.class` in the same / current directory. Then I tried both with `java -cp ./ MyClass` and `java MyClass` and same error. I also tried running with `java -cp /Users/someuser/Documents/workspace/MainPackage/src/com/foo/root`, also same error.

Comment: Have you attempted to the class path without the package specifier? IE: `-cp /Users/someuser/Documents/workspace/MainPackage/src`?

Comment: @Mark: Yup. Tried on all directories recursively with `-cp /Users/someuser/Documents/workspace/MainPackage/src` and still the same error. This error is going to drive me crazy. I can't find anything, anywhere.

Comment: Can you provide full command you are using to start java with the above class path?

Comment: @Mark: While I am within starting from `/Users/someuser/Documents/workspace/MainPackage/src/com/foo/root` directory to all the way up to `/Users/someuser/Documents/workspace` recursively, I ran this same command `java -cp /Users/someuser/Documents/workspace/MainPackage/src MyClass`. Please note that I'm using `zsh` and `zsh` is capable of tab completion, and when I do it, it finds the `MyClass` compiled `.class` file... So I don't think it's a visibility problem.

Comment: Doh!  When running main classes they should be fully qualified class name.  What error does the following give you? `java -cp /Users/someuser/Documents/workspace/MainPackage/src com.foo.root.MyClass`